# How is seastar::thread better than a stackless coroutine?

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine, seastar

I looked at this question: [Is seastar::thread a stackful coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72135948/is-seastarthread-a-stackful-coroutine)

In a comment to the answer, Botond Dénes wrote:

> That said, seastar::thread still has its (niche) uses in the post-coroutine world as it supports things like waiting for futures in destructors and catch clauses, allowing for using RAII and cleaner error handling. This is something that coroutines don't and can't support.

Could someone elaborate on this? What are the cases when 'things like waiting for futures in destructors and catch clauses' are impossible with stackless coroutines, but possible with `seastar::thread` (and alike)?

And more generally, what are the advantages of `seastar::thread` over C++20 stackless coroutines? Do all stackful coroutine implementations (e.g. those in Boost) have these same advantages?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably heard about the RAII (*resource acquisition is initialization*) idiom in C++, which is very useful for ensuring that resources get released even in case of exceptions. In the classic, synchronous, C++ world, here is an example:

```cpp
{
    someobject o = get_an_o();
    // At this point, "o" is holding some resource (e.g., an open file)
    call_some_function(o);
    return;
    // "o" is destroyed if call_some_function() throws, or before the return.
    // When it does, the file it was holding is automatically closed.
}
```

Now, let's consider asynchronous code using Seastar. Imagine that `get_an_o()` takes some time to do its work (e.g., open a disk file), and returns a `future<someobject>`. Well, you might think that you can just use stackless coroutines like this:

```cpp
    someobject o = co_await get_an_o();
    // At this point, "o" is holding some resource (e.g., an open file)
    call_some_function(o);
    return;
```

But there's a problem here... Although the `someobject` *constructor* could be made asynchronous (by using a factory function, `get_an_o()` in this example), the `someobject` **destructor** is still synchronous... It gets called by C++ when unwinding the stack, and it can't return a future! So if the object's destructor does need to wait (e.g., to flush the file), you can't use RAII.

Using a `seastar::thread` allows you to still use RAII because the destructor now **can** wait. This is because in a `seastar::thread` any code - including a destructor, may use `get()` on a future. This doesn't return a future from the destructor (which we can't) - instead it just "pauses" the stackful coroutine (switches to other tasks and later returns back to this stack when the future resolves).